# Last value in group by clause

Tags: mysql

[image]

Hi All, Please see attached image. Here I have a table "inv_stock" with "stockID" as primary key. I want to write a query to show stock quantity of each product with a column "Last vendor" using group by "invProductID"
I tried this query

```
SELECT inv_stock.invProductID, inv_stock.vendorID, SUM( inv_stock.quantity ) AS quantity
FROM inv_stock
GROUP BY inv_stock.invProductID
ORDER BY inv_stock.stockID, inv_stock.created DESC
```

But instead showing last vendorID it shows first vendorID

[image]

Second image is the desired result i want from query
Please help

Comment: his should not work. It probably does, because your `invProductID` is the primary key... Anyway you should add an aggregate function to your `vendorID` field!

Comment: The latest vendor is defined as max(inv_stock.created) per invProductID or  stockID (this is not clear from your question), hence the duplicate.